# Django REST Framework create and update nested objects

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create or update a nested object if the object exists, I tried to use the create_or_update method, now the create works fine, but the update failed and said the pk already existed.

My Model:

```
class ContentHotel(models.Model):
    hotel_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, blank=True, primary_key=True)
    star = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'content_hotels'
        ordering = ('hotel_id',)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.hotel_id)


class RateHotel(models.Model):
    rate_hotel_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    content_hotel = models.ForeignKey(ContentHotel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='rate_hotels')
    source_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'rate_hotels'
        ordering = ('rate_hotel_id',)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.rate_hotel_id)
```

My Serializers:

```
# To handle RateHotel object operations
class RateHotelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = RateHotel
        fields = __all__


# To handle nested object operations
class RateHotelSerializerTwo(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = RateHotel
        fields = __all__
        read_only_fields = ('content_hotel',)


class ContentHotelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rate_hotels = RateHotelSerializerTwo(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ContentHotel
        fields = __all__

    def create(self, validated_data):
        rate_hotels_data = validated_data.pop('rate_hotels')
        hotel_id = validated_data.pop('hotel_id')
        content_hotel, created = ContentHotel.objects.update_or_create(hotel_id=hotel_id, defaults={**validated_data})

        for rate_hotel_data in rate_hotels_data:
            rate_hotel_id = rate_hotel_data.pop('rate_hotel_id')
            RateHotel.objects.update_or_create(rate_hotel_id=rate_hotel_id, content_hotel=content_hotel,
                                               defaults=rate_hotel_data)

        return content_hotel

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        rate_hotels_data = validated_data.pop('rate_hotels')
        rate_hotels = list(instance.rate_hotels.all())
        for key in validated_data:
            instance.key = validated_data.get(key, instance.key)
        instance.save()

        for rate_hotel_data in rate_hotels_data:
            rate_hotel = rate_hotels.pop(0)
            for key in rate_hotel_data:
                rate_hotel.key = rate_hotel_data.get(key, rate_hotel.key)
            rate_hotel.save()

        return instance
```

JSON:

```
# Post Request - Create:
{
    "hotel_id": -1,
    "star": null,
    "rate_hotels": [{"rate_hotel_id": -1}]
}

# Post Response:
{
    "hotel_id": -1,
    "star": null,
    "rate_hotels": [
        {
            "content_hotel": -1,
            "rate_hotel_id": -1,
            "source_code": null,
        }
    ]
}

# Post Request - Update:
{
    "hotel_id": -1,
        "star": 2,
        "rate_hotels": [{"rate_hotel_id": -1, "source_code": "-1"}]
}

{
    "hotel_id": [
        "content hotel with this hotel id already exists."
    ],
    "rate_hotels": [
        {
            "rate_hotel_id": [
                "rate hotel with this rate hotel id already exists."
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status_code": 400
}
```

If I send a put request to update the nested object, the content hotel part works correctly, but the rate hotel part still said 'rate_hotel_id' already exists.

Can anyone help me fix this issue? I cannot find any related source online, thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Ziru - it feels like on a first glance inspection that you're trying to update the primary key for hotel rates...is this correct?

Comment: Hi again Ziru - if you are, please see my answer below... :)

Comment: Hi Micheal, thank you for your response, I am not trying to update the primary key, I will only update the fields except the primary key, but it gives me the error that the field of the primary key exists even if I keep the primary key the same.

Comment: It fees like you need to strip out your primary key overrides and just set them to unique keys.

Comment: Hi again Ziru - what would happen if you did `RateHotel.objects.update_or_create(rate_hotel_id=rate_hotel_id, content_hotel=content_hotel)` ... what is `rate_hotel_data` ? Is it an array, string?

Comment: I modified the code like what you said, the result it is the same, I think rate_hotel_data is `dict` since It has the key-value pair.

Comment: Hmmmmm....what is inside this dict?

Comment: I think it equals exactly what the json input has. And the problem is the update_or_create method only works in the creation part, and update part is not called even if the object exists. That is why it gives the error above since it was trying to create the object again.

Comment: I think I’ll need more time to think about this.

Comment: Thanks again, please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Can you post the urls you are sending those requests to? I have a feeling your issue is related to that rather than an issue with `update_or_create`

Comment: The URL shouldn't have any problem since the create worked fine, just the update part was never called.

Answer (score 1):

Your `create` code looks fine, but there are some bigger issues with your `update` code which you need to address before we can know where the real issue lies I think.

```
    for key in validated_data:
        instance.key = validated_data.get(key, instance.key)
    instance.save()
```

Here you are trying to loop through the values in the validated data and assign the values of that key to that attribute on the model. What you are actually doing is setting the attribute `key` on the model to the value of each key in `validated_data`. To better illustrate the issue I'll give you an example which corrects the issue:

```
    for key in validated_data:
        setattr(instance, key, validated_data.get(key, getattr(instance, key))
    instance.save()
```

Here rather than trying to set `instance.key` we use the python built-in method `setattr` to set the attribute with the name that matches the value of the variable `key` to the value which we pull from `validated_data`.

I'm not sure correcting this will solve your issue though. I'd make sure you're correctly sending your request to the correct url with the proper header values to get to the update method. It could be that Django Rest Framework is preventing the creation behind the scenes because it thinks you're sending the request as a create operation and it finds the primary keys already.

Comment: Thank you so much, Don. I will try to use the `setattr` method first, to see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: And you are right, the creations work fine, but seems like update_or_create method only do the creation part, and even if the object exists, it is still trying to create the object.

Comment: If the object exists, will the update_or_create method call the update method that I override?

Comment: My guess is that whatever you think you are doing to get to your `update` method isn't getting there. You should put a `pdb` breakpoint or something at that point to be sure you're getting there.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm, this looks like you could be looking for for "update if exists else create" use case, and Django has a `get_or_create()` method for performing what you want, see the docs here for reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

However, for you it could look something like this:

```
id = 'some identifier that is unique to the model you wish to lookup'
content_hotel, created = RateHotel.objects.get_or_create(
    rate_hotel_id=rate_hotel_id, 
    content_hotel=content_hotel, 
    defaults=rate_hotel_data
)

if created:
   # means you have created a new content hotel, redirect a success here or whatever you want to do on creation!
else:
   # content hotel just refers to the existing one, this is where you can update your Model
```

I would also advise removing the `hotel_id` and `hotel_rate_id` as primary keys:

```
class ContentHotel(models.Model):
        hotel_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, blank=True,)
        star = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

        class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = 'content_hotels'
            ordering = ('hotel_id',)

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.hotel_id)


    class RateHotel(models.Model):
        rate_hotel_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, unique=True,)
        content_hotel = models.ForeignKey(ContentHotel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='rate_hotels')
        source_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

        class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = 'rate_hotels'
            ordering = ('rate_hotel_id',)

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.rate_hotel_id)
```

The `update_or_create()` method does not accept a primary key, but can accept other unique database fields to perform the update:

So, an `update_or_create()` would look like so:

```
obj, created = Person.objects.update_or_create(
    first_name='John', last_name='Lennon',
    defaults={'first_name': 'Bob'},
)
```

Comment: For the update_or_create method, I used primary key so I can check whether the object with this pk exists, if exist then update, else create a new object with this pk.

Comment: I don't have other unique fields to track the object, do you have any solution about this?

Comment: If you know the primary key of the model you wish to update, use that for sure! You can't update_or_create by passing in the primary key unfortunately. So do a `get_or_create`, if `created` is `False` then you know you need to update an existing Model.

Comment: What can happen tho when you do a `get_or_create()` is that your lookup on a primary key *AND* some other data returns a get of false (even tho the primary key exists)...then when it tries to create - it throws another error (integrity error) when you attempt to create an object with the same ID.

Comment: So just pass in the primary key of the object you wish to `get_or_create()` - then, as mentioned, if created all is good - if created is false, you know it already exists - then simply update the data that you know is associated to this primary key.

Comment: The issue here wouldn't even be with the `update_or_create` as the error is thrown in the `update` method which doesn't use `update_or_create`

Comment: `update_or_create` needs a primary key, or some other unique identifier in order to do the lookup to know which model to update. The `defaults` are then used to update the model or default the values if one needs to be created.

Comment: @Don Hi Don - I think there's an integrity error thrown when the user is attempting to `update_or_create()` - I would advise using a unique field as above, but it looks like it's trying to get something that doesn't match all of the requirements (i.e., unique field is this AND some other field is that) and then fails on the update because the unique field already exists)...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178708/discussion-between-don-and-micheal-j-roberts).

Comment: @Don So what I have advised to do is *just* do a lookup on the uniquely identifiable field. I think that should then work for both `get_or_create()` and/or `update_or_create()`

Comment: Thank you, Micheal. I will try to use the get_or_create method to see if it works, I have to make hotel_id as pk so that I can match the RateHotel with the ContentHotel.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh - you may need to use a `ForeignKey` field...this is the best way to link the two and provides easy ways to link two objects/Models in both the view and template layer of your Django project...

Comment: I do have the foreign key in the RateHotel model, but the foreign key would match the primary key of the parent object, right?

Comment: You can access one Model’s fields from the other, and vice versa. If you need to have a unique ID for a field, you don’t have to set it to be the primary key and vice versa. So one of your Hotels could have a code of 11230 which uniquely identifies it, but also a primary key of 1.

Comment: This project is based on an existed database and the RateHotel model has a predefined field name 'content_hotel_id' matched with the field 'hotel_id' of the ContentHotel model, that is why I have to make 'hotel_id' as a pk so that ContentHotel and RateHotel are matched.